# Exporting Git release branch

Tags: git-branch, git-tfs, git-archive

I'm using TFS-GIT and I was wondering if its possible to extract everything that's been committed into a release branch to a ZIP. I've looked at an example and it insinuates everything in that branch would be extracted. I'm just looking to extract the files which have been added/updated with the folder structure of where the changes reside.

The reason I need to do this is because I cannot automatically deploy my code via TFS deploy, Jenkins or any other means to the live servers due to organisation rules, therefore I can only upload the files manually.

I've used the following command, the zip file is created but nothing is added to the zip.

```
git archive --format zip --output c:\zipfile.zip release_1.1
```

Thanking you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I've found [this](http://www.marco-bunge.com/2016/01/26/deployment-strategy-with-git/) which does what I needed.

```
git archive -o update.zip HEAD $(git diff --name-only HEAD@{"2016-01-15 00:00:00"} --diff-filter=ACMRTUXB)
```